# To configure tethering as two step login in CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, security, tethering

I have given my password of wifi stations to group of people. 
However, I want to allow only specific people to login at specific time.

### Attempt

I could not enable a basic MAC filtering for devices. Without it, I think this is not possible without a third-party application or without a change in the default options of settings. 
I could not find anything that is designed for the purpose. 
I did not find an option in the settings which could enable such a feature. 
You can

- see which devices are connected to your network in the settings, and
- to signout all devices from your network at once

but you cannot determine

- which devices are allowed to be in your network at specific times.

---

How can you manually decide which device can connect to my network?  I am running Cyanogenmod 13 (Android 6.0), unrooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you manually decide which device can connect to my network?

*hostapd*, a deamon that manages access point in Android (supports Linux and FreeBSD) is controlled by the configuration file `hostapd.conf` located under `/data/misc/wifi`. At least in my device, the configuration file *inter alia* notes:

```
# Station MAC address -based authentication
# Please note that this kind of access control requires a driver that uses
# hostapd to take care of management frame processing and as such, this can be
# used with driver=hostap or driver=nl80211, but not with driver=madwifi.
# 0 = accept unless in deny list
# 1 = deny unless in accept list
# 2 = use external RADIUS server (accept/deny lists are searched first)
macaddr_acl=0

# Accept/deny lists are read from separate files (containing list of
# MAC addresses, one per line). Use absolute path name to make sure that the
# files can be read on SIGHUP configuration reloads.
accept_mac_file=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd.accept
deny_mac_file=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd.deny
```

The configuration defaults to

```
0 = accept unless in deny list
```

while you need

```
1 = deny unless in accept list
```

To do just that, change the value from 0 to 1 in `macaddr_acl`, mention the MAC address of the target(s) which should be allowed to authenticate with your hotspot in the file *hostapd.accept*, start or restart the hotspot and see the magic.

Example of *hostapd.accept*:

```
# List of MAC addresses that are allowed to authenticate (IEEE 802.11)
# with the AP. Optional VLAN ID can be assigned for clients based on the
# MAC address if dynamic VLANs (hostapd.conf dynamic_vlan option) are used.
60:XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB
8c:BB:AA:ZZ:YY:XX
```

In above example file, only the machines with those MAC addresses are allowed to authenticate with my hotspot. Any machine with MAC address other than those two would repeatedly failed to authenticate.

Unfortunately, you may not be able to make any good use of this solution without root access.

**Note:** this solution is tested on an unofficial build of CM13.